# How to align the <td> at center in a dynamic HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I referred this [generate-html-table-using-javascript](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/generate-html-table-using-javascript.html) webpage and created a table. It works fine. In the javascript function it places the items as left aligned. How do I access the  element and align it to center?

Here is my javascript function

```js
function addRow() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" style="width: 65px;" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="Javascript:deleteRow(this)">';
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = '<input id="workloadDescription" style="width: 138px;" name="workloadDescription" type="text" value="Description"/>';

}
```

```html
<table border="1" align="center" id="myTableData" span style="width:1580px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="green" align="center" style="width: 75px;overflow: hidden;">
        <font color="white">Operation</font>
      </td>
      <td bgcolor="green" align="center" style="width: 140px;overflow: hidden;">
        <font color="white">Workload <br> Description
        </font>
      </td>
  </thead>
</table>
```

The HTML looks like this
[image]

But I want the button to be aligned in the center.

Comment: You forgot a 'c' in 'javasript:....'

Comment: Thank u. Corrected it in my code and in this post

Comment: The label Javascript is not needed here `Javascript:deleteRow`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your code to below, add `margin:auto; display:block;` to your button this will make button center

```
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" style="width: 65px; margin:auto; display:block;" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="Javascript:deleteRow(this)">';
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is adding `text-align:center;` to your table like so

```
<table border="1" align="center" id="myTableData" span style="width:1580px; text-align:center;"
```

Comment: Thank You. How do I align the button to the center

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep your styles separate from JavaScript.

With JavaScript you should add a new class to the button:

```
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" style="width: 65px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-centered" onClick="Javascript:deleteRow(this)">';
```

In your CSS file, you style that button:

```
.btn-centered {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank You. That's a bootstrap.css button. I cannot add style to it. Its not about aligning the text of the button. I want to align the button itself to the center

Comment: Ofcourse you can add style to it. You can add whatever styles you want. From what I know an `input` is an `inline` element so center should work...

Answer (score 1):

To align itens you can use `margin: auto;` and `text-align:center;` 
https://jsfiddle.net/r84tcq5c/

Answer (score 1):

Before writing the CSS for this I recommend you to wrap the td elements inside a div and the below CSS will do the rest for you.

```
#myTableData tr td div {text-align:center; }
```

This will center your div.

Div by itself is a blockelement. Therefor you need to define the style to the div how to behave.

Find Your Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ey36s317/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `text-align: center` on `<td>` as follow:

```
tbody > tr > td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

If you want to center only the content of first `<td>`, select the first child:

```
tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j106656c/)